# Mysqli_stmt_get_result returning fatal error in PHP 5.5.3

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am running an apache2 local dev server with php 5.5.3 installed. For some reason I am getting the error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()
```

on all my pages. I have read on the php documentation that the get_result() method requires the MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd), however on the MySQL website it says "As of PHP 5.4, the mysqlnd library is a php.net compile time default to all PHP MySQL extensions". I have tried installing php5-mysqlnd anyways and when I do it overwrites my previous mysql and mysqli conf files, causing me to get the error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

and when I reinstall php5-mysql it removes the mysqlnd package. I'm not really concerned with installing the packages I am more wondering why mysqlnd isn't recognized as a package in PHP 5.5.3 as it should be, and how can I enable it? Thanks in advance!

Apache 2 server on Ubuntu 13.10 running:

```
[~]$ php5 --version
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2 (cli) (built: Oct  9 2013 14:49:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group

[~]$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

EDIT:

I have already added the extensions to my php.ini file located at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. The file reads:

```
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so

extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/json.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqlnd.so
```

Comment: you still need to enable the `mysqli extension`.

Answer (score 5):

Check your `php.ini` to check if the extension for MySQLi is uncommented.. An example of what it should look like would be:

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

If this has a `;` then remove this, save the changes to php.ini and restart apache by invoking:

```
/etc/init.d/apache restart
```

and if your not sure where php.ini is located, create a simple page with:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

and check the line:

> Loaded Configuration File:     dir/to/php.ini

Or even run `phpinfo();` to begin with and check:

[image: MySQLI Enabled in phpinfo]

Comment: I have already enabled the extension in my php.ini file. Please see my edit for more information.

Comment: @lhasson Sorry for the delay, check your php error log, to check if the extension is loaded/picked up in the extension directory `/ext/*.*`

Comment: under the error log I get this error - `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
I think the problem is that when I sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd it return 1 to be removed and 1 to install. Removing: "php5-mysql" and installing: "php5-mysqlnd", which isn't what I want.

Comment: Then `mysqlnd.so` hasn't been count in the extension directory

Comment: @lhasson It also goes without saying. The exampled php.ini I have given is off my Local development machine (windows) `*.so` is the Linux alternative to `*.dll` files